# How does Google App Engine deployment work?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've tried to find detailed description how does the Google App Engine deployment work, but still no luck.

Can you explain this process step-by-step? I mean application signing, uploading etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be only one step to deployment: `appcfg update yourapp/`. Once you run that command, Google takes care of everything else. For more in-depth detail, see [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp)

Comment: I need explanation of the deployment process (how does it works etc), not usage